# Caterpillar?-Kindly help in identifying it.

Tags: insects, caterpillar

This creature on the photo was hiding in the tree and was moving bit quickly. Seemed like a caterpillar which eats moringa..  Can somebody help in identifying it. [image]

Comment: Knowing where you are in the world and the size of this caterpillar is important, but it's probably  a moth, possibly one of the Halysidota

Comment: @Bamboo I live in india.

Comment: Can't find this exact one, but white marked tussock moth larvae is the closest, there are loads, but I'm not being shown any native or endemic in India - google is studiously ignoring 'India' in my search terms and showing American ones instead, no matter how I rephrase the search

Comment: @Bamboo Yes of course, after searching based on your comments, i find that white marked tussok moth is the closest one that i could figure out. Thanks again. Can you make that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely one of the Halysidota, or specifically Orgyia, which are moths - this larvae I can't pin down exactly, but the closest is white marked tussock moth. That particular moth larvae has irritant hairs, so best not touched with bare fingers, but I'm not entirely sure which one yours is. Info on Tussock moths generally here https://www.thoughtco.com/tussock-moth-caterpillars-4097354